# What is the difference between pattern and shape in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am looking into the docs [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-node) but could not decipher much out from there. If someone can please define me in simple terms what shape is and then what pattern is.

Answer (score 1):

**Patterns** are used to **describe the shape** of the data you’re looking for.
A shape is a representation of the pattern(graph).

**Nodes are represented using circles and relationships are represented using arrows between them.**

In the following query

```
MATCH (user)
RETURN user
LIMIT 1
```

- The pattern is `(user)`
- Shape for the same is:
  [image]

**And for the following query:**

```
MATCH (me)-[:KNOWS]->(friend)
WHERE me.name = 'Filipa'
RETURN friend.name
```

- The pattern is `(me)-[:KNOWS]->(friend)`
- Shape for the same is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you want to draw a data model on a whiteboard. You'd probably use *shapes* like circles to represent nodes, and lines or arrows to represent relationships.

The Cypher language was designed to use *patterns* that look a bit like the shapes you'd draw on the board.

For example, instead of a circle shape for a node, the equivalent Cypher pattern would be something like this (if we wanted to refer to the node by the variable "a"):

```
(a)
```

And, instead of a line or arrow for a relationship between 2 nodes, in Cypher you could use one of these patterns:

```
(a)--(b)
(a)-->(b)
```

Patterns can be a lot more complex, but this is the basic idea.